# Angular 6: Adding data to database using ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I have an app which displays just movies from external api, so I have added comment section to my app for single movie,  my problem is when a user enter a comment in a movie called ***"TITANIC"***  I can see the comment added to all movies `This is wrong`, what I want is comment added to a movie TITANIC should not be displayed to other movies.

Here is what I have:

> server.js **UPDATE**

```
router.post('/comments', function(req, res) {
  var comment = new Comments(req.body);
  comment.save()
   .then(item => {
   res.status(200).json({'comment': 'comment added successfully'});
   })
   .catch(err => {
   res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
   });

});
```

> service.js

```
  // Adds comments
      addReview(author, description): Observable<any> {
        const uri = 'http://localhost:8000/movies/comments/';
        const obj = {
          author: author,
          description: description
        };
        return this.http.post(uri, obj);
      }

  // Return Comments
  getComments(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${apiUrl + this.commentsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

> component.ts

```
addReview(author, description) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(author, description).subscribe(success => {
        this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
        // get the id
        this.activeRouter.params.subscribe((params) => {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
          let id = params['id'];
          this.moviesService.getComments(id)
            .subscribe(comments => {
              console.log(comments);
              this.comments = comments;
            });
        });
    }, error => {
        this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    });
}
```

***Question***

> What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Code looks okay.please post getComments service method as well.

Comment: What is the service method addReview supposed to do? I thought it should add one comment to one specific movie but the URL reads different. I had imagined something like http://localhost:8000/movies/{movieId}/comments/

Comment: @baj9032 check the qn now, I have added the method u requested getComments from service

Comment: @addreview method I want a comment should be added to a specific movie by using ID, right now it  comments are added to all movies not to a specific movie, I am stuck here how to solve this problem, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the corresponding movie id to the POST request adding a new comment.

```
addReview(movieId, author, description): Observable<any> {
        const obj = {movieId, author, description};
```

2) When you request the comments for a movie by its id, use the `movieId` in your database query (depends on your database and ORM)

If you're using mongodb and mongoose, it'd be something like:

```
router.get('/comments/:movieId', function(req, res) {
  const movieId= request.params.movieId;
  Comments.find({ movieId });
```

Comment: and what about componet ?

Comment: The component calls the addReview method, right? It just needs to pass movieId as a parameter. Was that your question?

Comment: Yes, I tried implementing your method , but it doesnt work .

Comment: I just want to post the comment to a specific ID, the problem starts with post for comments method in server .

Comment: What's the problem? If you're using mongoose, you need to add the movieId to your comment schema.

Comment: I mean this is the problem `router.post('/comments', function(req, res) {
  var comment = new Comments(req.body);
  comment.save()
   .then(item => {
   res.status(200).json({'comment': 'comment added successfully'});
   })
   .catch(err => {
   res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
   });

});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174062/discussion-between-kaczka-pojebana-and-kim-kern).

Answer (score 0):

You should **/post** to a specific movie ID where you add the new comment under its **comments** field array for example.

Also, having **/comments** is a bad practice since what you really want is posting to a specific movie with its attached comment. Something like the following:

```
router.post('/movie/:id/newcomment:', function(req, res) {
  Movie.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
      .then(movie => {
         movie.comments.push(req.body.comment);
         movie.save();
             .then(result => {
             res.status(200).json({'message': 'comment added successfully'});})
             .catch(err => {
              res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
            });
        }
});
```

But the main problem here is that you misunderstand what exactly you need to do.

You fetch data from an existing API, yet you want to add specific comments to specific movies from the fetched data.

You cannot achieve it without having full control on your external API.

What you could actually do is build a client side data structure to hold all the fetched data, and then add to each movie object inside that data structure another property which will be named **comments** and an **ID** property, so you can later access that data structure by ID and update a specific property.

Comment: Hi, what about sevice method to addReview suppose too look after these changes?